# invocating same jquery script multiple times

Tags: jquery

How can i invoke a jquery script multiple times by using a php foreach loop.The jquery script draws a pie chart based on data present in the session for every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is server side, JavaScript (jQuery) is client side. You cannot use PHP to invoke a JavaScript function.

Comment: But you can print out JavaScript with PHP and the function will be invoked

Comment: Yes, of course. It does not make any sense, but you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

This would call `jsFunction()` 10 times with params from 0 to 10

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
<?php
    for($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++;){
        echo 'jsFunction(' + $i + ')';
    }
?>
});
</script>
```

Which is equivalent to simply writing (and will output this to page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        jsFunction(0);
        jsFunction(1);
        jsFunction(2);
        jsFunction(3);
        jsFunction(4);
        jsFunction(5);
        jsFunction(6);
        jsFunction(7);
        jsFunction(8);
        jsFunction(9);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It'll be better if you put the `<script>` tags outside the loop

Comment: this would write ten times the script tag, it is better to let the script tag outside the loop...

Answer (score 0):

You can write a new script tag or jQuery function in the foreach loop

```
    echo '<script>';
    foreach(....){
        echo 'drawPieFunction();';
    }
    echo '</script>';
```

highly recommend against this though since it has next to no good uses

Answer (score 0):

You can also adapt your javascript function to accept arrays as parameter.

If so you can via PHP set values of an array and then call the function only one time:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
    echo "var arrayPies = [";

    for($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++){
        echo ($i<10) ? "$i," : "$i";
    }

    echo "];\n";

    echo "callPieFunction(arrayPies);";
?>
</script>
```

The above code will output something like this:

```
var arrayPies = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
callPieFunction(arrayPies);
```